# Showing NumberFormatException in jsp while converting string to integer

Tags: java, jsp, numberformatexception

```
   int s1=123;String s2="";
   input 1st value`
    out.print("<script> var s1= prompt('OTP send','');</script>");
     s2="<script>document.write(s1)</script>";
  
    int i2=Integer.parseInt(s2);
```

converting string showing NumberFormatException:`

```
if(s1==i2) 
  print result here
else
  print result here
```

Comment: you are taking input from `js` ? and comparing that value with `jsp variable` ? why ?

Comment: If the condition gets true, i need to perform some db operations